# Is long waste pipe OK for food waste disposer?

Tags: plumbing, garbage-disposal

I am interested in food waste disposer, the model is [InSinkErator Evolution 200 premium food waste disposer](http://insinkerator.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/insinkeratoruk/food-waste-disposers/evolution-200-food-waste-disposer).

What concerns me is that in the kitchen we have a long horizontal waste pipe under the floor (see the attached picture). So my question is if such pipe could couse problems? F.i. grinded food keeps in the horizontal pipe.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are you sure its really horizontal? Have you put a level on it? The 'normal' slope for a waste pipe that I'm aware of is only about 1 in 50 (1 in 48 if you're working at 1/4 inch per foot).

Comment: @brhans ok, I am no sure regarding slope, will ask. Anyway - if there is 'normal' slope - could the length of the pipe cause problems? Is diameter of the pipe suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 1/4" per foot (a normal drain line) you should be fine. If the pipe is totally horizontal it may not work well over time as oils , grease soap scum and just normal organic matter will cause backups. 10' with the drop from the disposal may not be a problem even if close to horizontal. Make sure to run water for a little while after the disposal is clear to flush the material down the drain. If greasy stuff use Hot water and you will probably be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Thats fine if there is the grade like they said, if you have a level look for about a quarter bubble.  Or measure to the floor from center of at both ends of the section of the pipe.  There should be a 2 and a half inch difference.